# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

This question has come up in a past paper before and I'm not sure what steps I need to take to prove this. I thought all you had to do was show that $\sqrt{3}$ has a monic polynomial which it is the solution to - clearly ($x^2-3$). What else do I need to show?

Comment: Do you know if it is enough to show that $\sqrt{3}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$? If not, an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt{3},$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}.$ You need to show that such an arbitrary element is integral over $\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Ok, so I show that the monic polynomial for that arbitrary element is $x^2-2ax+(a^2-3b^2)$. Is this answer comprehensive?

Comment: Simple answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, I think it is enough.